# Grouping consequent entries subject to condition

Tags: sql

I have this sql challenge which I would be happy to be helped with:

The challenge is: given list of transactions, I have to treat multiple transactions as if there are one, but only if the period of time between the two consequent transactions is less than 2 weeks.

For example, if a customer made 3 transactions,

- the first one on 01.05.2020,
- the second one on 08.05.2020
- and the third one on 20.05.2020 - all the 3 should be treated as if they took place simultaneously,

Since there are less than 2 weeks between each 2 consequent entries.

If the fourth transaction took place on 20.7.2020 it should be treated separately since there are more than two weeks between this one and the previous one.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify groups using `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_datetime > datetime - interval '14 day' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by customer order by datetime) as transaction_group
from (select t.*, lag(datetime) over (partition by customer order by datetime) as prev_datetime
      from t
     ) t;
```

Datetime functions are notoriously database dependent.  So the exact date/time functions might be different on your database.  But the idea is the same.